# How to find the GPIO mapping for 'boot switch' in Beagle bone black Rev C?

Tags: beagleboneblack

I have a Beagle Bone black Rev C and as a part of my learning ,I would want to configure the Boot switch button as an input GPIO .

can some one please help me how to find the GPIO mapping related to the Boot switch pin? I have tried looking the expansion headers in the BBB_SRM document with no results .
[image]

Thanks a lot in advance .

Answer (score 1):

Your main source would be BeagleBone Black Rev schematic, thankfully full schematic of the BBB is readily available.

Then on page 6 you will find boot connections and Boot switch in particular is connected to SYS_BOOT2 and LCD_DATA2 that eventually connected to GPIO2_8